# Realm index and primary key

Tags: ios, objective-c, realm

I think I have read it somewhere which say that `primaryKey` in realm object is indexed.

However, if I manually declare `indexedProperties` does this override index on `primaryKey` and I need to manually include `primaryKey` to the indexed list?

The document [here](https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/#indexed-properties) doesn't say anything about this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Katsumi from Realm here. A primary key property will be indexed automatically.

See https://github.com/realm/realm-object-store/blob/a7edffdec9795d3371838daf2b14641d72825698/src/property.hpp#L51

So you do not need specify indexed if the property is primary key. But there is no problem/effect specifying both indexing and primary key.